# Day of year format x axis matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with cummulative rainfall data.

The columns are `'dayoftheyear', '1981', '1982' .... '2019'`

I plot the data using the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,10))

ax.set_title('Cummulative rainfall in Chennai hydrological basin')
ax.set_xlabel('day of the year')
ax.set_ylabel('total rainfall in mm')
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")


df.plot(ax=ax,
        x='dayofyear',
        y=years_string,
        colormap='gray',
        legend=False,
        alpha=0.2)

df.plot(ax=ax,
        x='dayofyear',
        y=['2015','2016','2017','2018'],
        alpha=0.7,
        colormap='plasma')

df.plot(ax=ax,
        x='dayofyear',
        y='2019',
        color='red',
        linewidth=3)

fig.savefig('test.jpg')
```

and the results looks really good[image]

However the day of the year can be hard to understand and I would like to add major tick marks per month and the day of the month if possible. I found this [resource](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html) and tried to get it to work to no avail. Is there a simple way to change the xaxis ticks without converting the data?

full code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rutgerhofste/3fbe3f8758d54f7c66c77844edcacf94/untitled1.ipynb)

Comment: You can convert your dayofyear column to true dates.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Easiest solution was to convert to datetime's. Set plotting of the axis using the [format page](http://strftime.org/)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Y2019M07D31_RH_Chennai_v01.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rutgerhofste/666c1a01e9f2724de1451ee9b27d9cdd/y2019m07d31_rh_chennai_v01.ipynb
"""

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.dates as dates

df =pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rutgerhofste/94b9035bdcaf1163ff910a08ad3239a3/raw/db2efe21aa980418558010695db08af5c27b616c/cummulative.csv')

df.head()

df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['dayofyear'], format='%j')

years = list(range(1981,2014+1))

def string(year):
  return str(year)

years_string = list(map(string,years))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,10))

ax.set_title('Cummulative rainfall in Chennai hydrological basin')

df.plot(ax=ax,
        x='date',
        y=years_string,
        colormap='gray',
        legend=False,
        alpha=0.2)

df.plot(ax=ax,
        x='date',
        y=['2015','2016','2017','2018'],
        alpha=0.7,
        colormap='viridis')

df.plot(ax=ax,
        x='date',
        y='2019',
        color='red',
        linewidth=3)

ax.set_xlabel('Month')
ax.set_ylabel('total rainfall in mm')
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")

major_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_format)


ax.xaxis.grid(linestyle=':')
fig.savefig('test.pdf')
```

[image]

[Script](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rutgerhofste/666c1a01e9f2724de1451ee9b27d9cdd/y2019m07d31_rh_chennai_v01.ipynb)

Answer (score -2):

Your question is clear, you should post a sample of the dataframe as well of what you are dealing with. You can select where you want your ticks on the x-axis with this line of code.

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
```

Comment: there is a link to the full script including data and example